# How can I remove slashes from strings?

Tags: php

I am trying to do some PHP programming concepts and I am not aware of some in-build functions. So my doubt is:

In PHP, how to remove slashes from strings? Is there any function available in PHP for this??

e.g.

```
$string="people are using Iphone/'s instead of Android phone/'s";
```

Comment: Check your PHP configuration that magic quotes are disabled: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc - see as well http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You can use stripslashes() function.

```
<?php
$str = "Is your name O\'reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O'reilly?
echo stripslashes($str);
?>
```

Comment: How does this get upvoted when it only removes \ and not / and the OP wanted to remove / ?

Comment: Exactly... it does not remove forward slashes.

Answer (score 41):

You can do a number of things here, but the two approaches I would choose from are:

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$string = "people are using Iphone/'s instead of Android phone/'s";
$result = str_replace('/','',$string);
echo $result;
// Output: people are using Iphone's instead of Android phone's
```

If the slashes are backward slashes (as they probably are), you can use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
$string = "people are using Iphone\\'s instead of Android phone\\'s";
$result = stripslashes($string);
echo $result;
// Output: people are using Iphone's instead of Android phone's
```

Comment: is this a bad example

Answer (score 5):

backslashes need escaping

```
$newstr = "<h1>Hello \ fred</h1>";

echo str_replace('\\','',$newstr);
```

Comment: the question was to remove / not \

Answer (score 2):

If it is a quoted string. Use [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

Comment: This is the answer. `$string = stripslashes($string);`

Comment: No working for me. I wanna remove "/" no "\"

Answer (score 2):

you can use function like

```
 $string = preg_replace ("~/~", "", $string);
```

Comment: But u can also use it.its just another way of doing the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Heres what I use

```
function removeSlashes($string = '')
{
    return stripslashes(str_replace('/', '', $string));
}
```

Test

```
echo $this->removeSlashes('asdasd/asd/asd//as/d/asdzfdzdzd\\hd\h\d\h\dw');
```

Output

```
asdasdasdasdasdasdzfdzdzdhdhdhdw
```

Comment: It was the only thing that helped me to get rid of '/// in a string'. When I used just str_replace, it would always leave single slashes, using both seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use varian preg

```
$string="people are using Iphone/'s instead of Android phone/'s";

echo $string = preg_replace('/\//', '', $string);
```

```css
body, html, iframe { 
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  overflow: hidden ;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://ideone.com/uIBINP" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method to remove single forward slashes.

I used `str_replace` to strip the slashes out. It still did not work for me, I had to go and change all the double quotes in the database to single quotes, update the table, then change it back to double quotes for it to work. Weird.

```
str_replace('\\', '', $content)
```